# {% url %} gives NoReverseMatch error

Tags: python, django, django-1.4

I'm using Django 1.4 and am getting the following error

```
Reverse for 'dj' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'dj_name': u"John O'Callaghan"}' not found.
```

Using `John OCallaghan` instead of `John O'Callaghan` in the database works perfectly fine and doesn't give an error.

Here is the line that gives the error

```
<a href="{% url 'dj' dj_name=dj.name %}"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ dj.img }}" class="img-rounded" id="dj_img"/></a>
```

I read at quite a few places that you are not supposed to use quotes in `{% url %}` in Django 1.4. Using `{% url dj dj_name=dj.name %}` instead of `{% url 'dj' dj_name=dj.name %}` gives the following error instead

```
TypeError - cannot concatenate 'str' and 'DJ' objects
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('hunt.views',
    url(r'^$', views.landing, name='landing'),
    url(r'^top100/$', views.top100, name='top100'),
    url(r'^top100/(?P<dj_name>[a-zA-Z0-9 &-]+)/$', views.dj, name='dj'),
)
```

Comment: The error is almost certainly in your url regex. You should post that.

Comment: Updated the question with **urls.py**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having seen your URL, I'm surprised at your surprise that it is not working with "O'Callaghan". Your regex specifies exactly the characters that it accepts: a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9, space, ampersand, and hyphen. Apostrophe is not there. If you want it to accept an apostrophe, you need to add it to that list.

```
r"^top100/(?P<dj_name>[a-zA-Z0-9 &-']+)/$"
```

Comment: I figured that out myself as soon as I posted the urls.py. Thanks for the help.